# Problems mixing javascript and jquery with XSL transformations, or something with function parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I'm trying to have navigation buttons on my page load content files, but a couple of these files are XML and need to be styled with XSL transformations. I've had success in the past using the XSL On the Client code from w3schools.com, so I've adapted that below. However, something doesn't appear to be working with my mix of javascript and jquery, or maybe I'm not passing the parameters correctly? Firebug tells me that it cannot load the 'xsl' variable. Does anything look wrong with this syntax? I'm very new at this and can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#aboutTextButton").click(function(){
        $('#contentContainer').load('about-text.html');
    });
    $("#aboutProjectButton").click(function(){
        $('#contentContainer').load('about-project.html');
    });
    $("#catalogButton").click(function(){
        displayResult("catalog.xml","xml-style2.xsl");
    });
    $("#transcriptionButton").click(function(){
        displayResult("behaviour.xml","xml-style2.xsl");
    });
}); 

//script to transform XML, adapted from w3schools.com 
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult(xml, xsl)
{
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("contentContainer").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="headerImg">
        <img src="cover.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="aboutTextButton">About the Text</a></li>
            <li><a id="aboutProjectButton">About the Project</a></li>
            <li><a id="catalogButton">Browse the Images</a></li>
            <li><a id="transcriptionButton">Read the Text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="contentContainer">
    </div>
```

Comment: [See this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) on the MDN site. Your use of ".importStylesheet()" is incorrect.

Comment: You don't often see XSL transformations applied via javascript. Most of the time, it's done on the server before the page is sent, although it's possible to send xml directly to the browser and and let the browser handle the xslt using a processing instruction like: `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="..." ?>` ... either way there's really no reason to involve javascript, as server-side is usually the preferred way, and client-side (without javascript) xsl is remarkably well-supported across browsers (even ie6 gets it almost 100% right), although rarely used.

Comment: I do see a lot of other people asking about it though, so maybe it's more common now. Anyway, consider whether you actually need to apply the xsl with javascript; you may be better off applying it on the server or letting the browser do it without using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call loadXMLDoc so the displayResults function isn't processing a xml doc it's processing the the file name that you pass the function. The first lines of displayResult should be:

```
xml = loadXMLDoc(xml);
xsl = loadXMLDoc(xsl);
```

Then your code should work.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.